# Load custom app.config to WCFTestClleint

Tags: c#, wcf, config, wcftestclient

Can I load my own app.config file just like it can be done in following link for WCFStorm ?.
http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/loading-client-appconfig-files.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's possible, take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dde72fbe-e741-48fd-a9e1-253800d5227a/is-any-way-to-change-wcf-test-client-config)

Comment: Yes. Your own app.config can take on any form just so long as there is a <system.serviceModel> block inside the root <configuration> block